# Application performance - possibly due to too many allocation on large object heap

Tags: .net, performance, heap-memory, sos

> EDIT: After another run of performance profiling can clearly see that
>   the performance is being affected by thread syncronization and DB
>   calls. Thanks for comments guys, helped me go back in the right
>   direction.

I was investigating an application which seems to be running slowly: effectively it is a work engine running in IIS/Dot Net 4.0. The work is mostly in memory calculation, but CPU does not spike and it looks as if the system kind of just hangs in between, but can see no evidence of locking in application code and neither in DB.

**Symptoms:** The calculation are not too complex and the system has been slowing down over the years, CPU never goes more than 7-8% (mostly). The only thing I see is the was the Memory (Active private working set) in task manager hitting really high numbers ~ shoots from about 500 MB to 2/3GB when I start the calculations.

I checked with few profilers, I can see most of the memory being is not actually being used by dot net.

[image: Memory Snapshot]

I took a crash dump (crash dump stats not related to pic above and was taken in seperate run) and confirmed it by windbg/sos.

> !heapstat -iu

I am not sure if my understanding about the stats is correct but looks like most of the memory is taken up by unrooted objects in Gen1/2, but if that is the case I would expect this memory to be reclaimed at some point of time during GC collection. I tried to recyle the app pool but I could see no effect on this unused memory.

[image]
I then tried to get the stats about live and dead objects using:

For the live objects I found the following:

```
!dumpheap -stat -live 

Count   TotalSize
611085  231816172
```

For the dead objects I found the following:

```
!dumpheap -stat -dead 

Count       TotalSize
19969810    1631716434
```

Also in terms of the biggest contributor (to dead objects) to this memory size I noted:

```
Count   TotalSize   Class Name                                              Total Size/Count    
2255867 144375488   System.Data.Listeners`1+Action`4[...                    64
1479    202166952   System.Decimal[]                                        136691.6511
7463    307861416   System.Data.RBTree`1+Node[[System.Int32, mscorlib]][]   41251.69717
9325607 447629136   System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple  48
```

I am not sure about free vs unrooted objects, but can see that the dead objects to live objects size is about the same as I can see using the profiler, and am more confused why the iterator object of 48bytes is getting allocted on the heap.

This is a third party library and they are using datasets heavily, also I can see that they are using enumerators (and boxing it during call to dispose).

I would like to understand:
1. Is this the right track to proceed and any pointers to find the cause.
2. Would like to understand why would the iterator get allocated on the heap as, it does not look like it passes the criterea in terms of size.
3. Considering if the use of dataset is the issue and it is third party library and am on dot net 4.5.0 ( so no heap compaction option available, recylce app pool also has no effect) any possible way to workaround the issue.

Comment: How much memory does the machine running this have?

Comment: The pie chart is horribly misleading, seems like a product that was designed only to diagnose workstation apps.  I see nothing wrong in the heap stats, just a very busy server app that runs on beefy hardware.  Seeing the gen#0 segments grow to nearly 100MB is impressive, but simply a side-effect of the GC dealing with server requests needing a lot of temporary memory to get the job done.  You could force less memory to be used with the gcServer element in the .config file, but that ought to make it quite a bit slower.  You'd make it faster, and use more memory, by caching data.

Comment: It is strange that you focus on memory usage, while the actual problem is slowness. You need to use a performance profiler to check where the time goes first. High memory usage might lead to slowness, but there are far more factors contributing to slowness directly.

Comment: Stupid question, have you checked the DB (indexes)?

Comment: @IanKemp Its a 32 GB machine, actually running on my desktop, but the performance profile on server is similar. DB indexes are ok, the application caches the DB objects so not expecting the hit from there. The iterator/enumerator being allocated is actually one of the cached object.

Comment: @LexLi I did do a performance profiling, where I found nothing significant, the CPU usages is consistently low both on my machine and server. Its not significantly multithreaded, so not expecting locking/waiting threads to be an issue, and yes the performance profiler did not pick anything up as well.

Comment: @HansPassant I did not understand why you called the snapshot misleading. I did try putting the gcServer element, did not cause significant change in the performance/memory profile. I was focussing on the heap, as the profiler was complaining of heap fragmentation and I see no reason for the heap to grow the size it does. My takeaway is to run another round of performance profiling and see if I missed anything.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that as people define slowness/hang to be very specific, and performance profiling aims to catch that. When a profiler captures all steps executed and how long each of them took, there must be some hints. Well, it's too vague to comment further here, as nobody but yourself has access to the profiling results. Hire a experienced consultant or simply open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: This is simple case when either your code or third party code has stored large datasets in Session or Application Storage. Avoid session and use Cache instead.